# Is there a logical reason why Amazon EC2 won't allow me to specify a port when using GRE?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, amazon-ec2, firewall, pptp

I want to set up PPTP in EC2 and am configuring a security group.  I've already selected the "custom protocol" and am using protocol 47 / GRE.  When I select this, the port section is read only.

Is there any intuitive reason that I shouldn't filter use port 1723 when a custom protocol is used?

Does it matter if I leave the other ports open (when protocol is GRE)?

Comment: GRE does not have ports.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton ... Are TCP/UDP the only ones that have ports? No matter what I type in the "custom protocol" section, the "ports" section is uneditable

Answer (score 2):

Do not get port 47 confused with [protocol 47](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1701). Opening port 47 on your firewall is not the same as allowing protocol 47 (GRE).

A PPTP tunnel is instantiated by communication to the peer on TCP port 1723. This TCP connection is then used to initiate and manage a second GRE tunnel to the same peer, so you need both opened.

Also, do not use [PPTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol#Security).

Comment: I corrected the typo.. I wrote port 47 when I meant protocol.

Comment: your question is little unclear now